# SQL PL/SQL dynamic variable binding

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to run below query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TABLE1
WHERE 
    COL1 = :DynamicValue1
    AND  COL2 = :DynamicValue2
USING 
    USERENTEREDVALUE1, USERENTEREDVALUE2;
```

I don't want to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

How can I use `using` keyword in select query?
When I run this I get pop up to enter value but it gives error
Ora-00933

Comment: try using DBMS_SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use substitution variables

```
DEFINE lname = 'Rogers'
DEFINE mgrid = 122

SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE last_name = '&lname'
AND manager_id  = '&mgrid';
```

When you run this in SQL developer or SQL* Plus, you get

```
old:SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE last_name = '&lname'
AND manager_id  = &mgrid
new:SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE last_name = 'Rogers'
AND manager_id  = 122

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 EMAIL                     PHONE_NUMBER         HIRE_DAT JOB_ID         SALARY COMMISSION_PCT MANAGER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -------------------- -------- ---------- ---------- -------------- ---------- -------------
        134 Michael              Rogers                    MROGERS                   650.127.1834         26-08-06 ST_CLERK         2900                       122            50
```

Or use  Bind variables

```
VARIABLE   lname VARCHAR2(40) 
VARIABLE  mgrid NUMBER 
EXEC :lname := 'Rogers'
EXEC :mgrid := 122
VARIABLE x REFCURSOR


BEGIN
     OPEN :x FOR SELECT *
                 FROM employees
                 WHERE last_name =:lname 
                 AND manager_id =:mgrid;
END;
/

    PRINT x
```

Result

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.



EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 EMAIL                     PHONE_NUMBER         HIRE_DAT JOB_ID         SALARY COMMISSION_PCT MANAGER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -------------------- -------- ---------- ---------- -------------- ---------- -------------
        134 Michael              Rogers                    MROGERS                   650.127.1834         26-08-06 ST_CLERK         2900                       122            50
```

Comment: Is there any way I can use in single statement? I am not using PL/SQL. Just want to run query from editor.

Comment: @AAD : if you run my first select query without defining the 2 variables, it does prompt you to input values, which substitutes the value u enter and gives u the query result

Comment: Yes but can't I combine that with 'using' keyword?

Comment: @AAD : well you can't. That's why you get the error as there is no such syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're doing `pl/sql`, but if you do, you can simply add variables to you query:

```
declare
    USERENTEREDVALUE1 VARCHAR2(100) := 'value1';
    USERENTEREDVALUE2 VARCHAR2(100) := 'value2';
    RESULTVALUE VARCHAR2(100);
begin

    SELECT COL3
      INTO RESULTVALUE
      FROM  (
                SELECT 'value1' COL1, 'value2' COL2, 'Ok' COL3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'value3' COL1, 'value4' COL2, 'NOK' COL3 FROM dual
            ) TABLE1
    WHERE COL1 = USERENTEREDVALUE1
      AND COL2 = USERENTEREDVALUE2;

    dbms_output.put_line('RESULTVALUE: ' || RESULTVALUE); 
end;
```

Comment: No I am not doing PL/SQL. I just want to run SQL query from editor with dynamic binding and would like to use 'using' keyword.

Comment: Okay.. I did remove your `pl/sql`-Tag